# Alamofire 4.0 in swift

Tags: ios, swift, migration, alamofire

```
 Alamofire.request(TWConstants.LoginUrl,
                          method: .post,
                          parameters: param as! [String : String],
                          encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                          headers: TWNetworkManager.getHeaderUser(username, passwd: passwd) as? [String : String]).responseJSON
```

this is my post request. The error is coming as:

> Extra argument 'method' in call

I am migrating my Alamofire version 3 to Alamofire version 4. I tried to look into documentation but nothing comes to help for me. could anybody help me in this?

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4 , Use this**

```
params = [
           "username" : "",
           "password" : "" ]

Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in
            print(response.result.value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Alamofire issue:](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1508#issuecomment-246207682)

> this kind of error appears when one argument is of the wrong type and the Swift interpreter believes that you're wrongly using the 
>   function:
>
> request(urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible)

That’s why the error says:

> **Extra argument 'method' in call**

In your example the optional “param” parameter has to be of `[String: Any]` type:

```
public typealias Parameters = [String: Any]
```

Comment: Alamofire.request(URLConvertible, method: HTTPMethod, parameters: Parameters?, encoding: ParameterEncoding, headers: HTTPHeaders?)  This is the POST request syntax I am using for this.

Comment: Yes, Parameters is a public typealias = [String: Any]

Answer (score 0):

```
        let parameter : [String : Any] = [
            "auth" : [
                "api_key" : "",
                "user_token" : "" 
            ],

            "mobile" : mobileNoTF.text!

        ]

        Alamofire.request("https://url", method:.post , parameters : parameter ,encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
            .responseJSON { response in

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
               }

                if((response.result.value) != nil) {
                    let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(response.result.value!)

                    //  self.compalinListArray.removeAll()

                    print(swiftyJsonVar)

                    if status == "success"

                    {


                    } else if status == "unauthorized"
                    {


                    }else if status == "error"
                    {
                        //else error
                    }
                }
        }


    }else {
       //else error
    }
```